# How to add menu when there is No Action Bar

Tags: android

I want create a menu in my application which has no action bar... I want to make it just like you can see in chrome browser... Please help me with this and sorry for I don't have any code I made for this purpose ....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are asking, so I will try to list all posible meanings:

### Use Toolbar(ActionBar)'s menu but layout doesn't have Toolbar:

Just add a toolbar to your layout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
...
</LinealLayout>
```

### Custom Toolbar

I have never tried to inflate Menu into a non-Toolbar and I think it is not possible. Please correct me if you have tried! So I think you must implement every view/button, etc... one by one.

### No toolbar, just menu (Popup ?)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/popup-menu-in-android-with-example/